# Sorting php array with arsort not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array: `Array ( [0] => 99a1 [8] => 75a4 [7] => 75a3 [6] => 75a2 [5] => 75a1 [9] => 150a5 [2] => 150a1 [4] => 150a1 [1] => 150a1 [3] => 131a1 )`.

I want to sort the array so that the first numbers would be 150a1, however when I run `arsort($_SESSION["highscore"]);`, It stays like the array above.

EDIT:

```
array_push($_SESSION["highscore"], $_SESSION['score'] . 'a' . $_SESSION['scoreNumber']);
    arsort($_SESSION["highscore"]);
    print_r($_SESSION["highscore"]);
    for ($i=0; $i <= count($_SESSION["highscore"]) - 1; $i++) { 
        if ($_SESSION["highscore"][$i] == $_SESSION['score'] . 'a' . $_SESSION['scoreNumber']) {

            $scoreInArray = $i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you show your code

Comment: @JohnConde There's the code.

Comment: Have you tried `arsort($_SESSION["highscore"], SORT_NATURAL);`

Comment: @NigelRen wow, It did work, thanks! If you want, make an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SORT_NATURAL` (similar to [`natsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)) will sort the string according to numerical as well as character order...

```
arsort($_SESSION["highscore"], SORT_NATURAL);
```